How to Use OpenAI Batch API in C#
I want to use Batch API of openai to get the response for my data. I am not sure can we do the same thing in c# which we do in python. In Python we upload a .jsonl file on the OpenAI server. Then the server reads the file to generate the response which is then stored in a file whose id is given to us by openai to retrieve the responses.
So how to this process in C#?
I have done till now but not working.
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public class OpenAIBatchClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _openAiApiKey;

    public OpenAIBatchClient(string openAiApiKey)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _openAiApiKey = openAiApiKey;

        // Set the authorization header
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _openAiApiKey);
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var content = new StreamContent(fileStream))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/jsonl");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/files", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
                return jsonResponse["id"].ToString(); // return the file ID
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error uploading file: {response.StatusCode} - {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateBatchAsync(string inputFileId)
    {
        var batchRequest = new
        {
            input_file_id = inputFileId,
            endpoint = "/v1/chat/completions",
            completion_window = "24h",
            metadata = new { 
                    description = "nightly eval job"
                }
        };

        var content = new StringContent(JObject.FromObject(batchRequest).ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/batches", content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            return jsonResponse["id"].ToString(); // return the batch ID
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error creating batch: {response.StatusCode} - {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
        }
    }


Now I want to do the same in C#, how can I do it?

What you posted is how you use a library to generate the actual HTTP calls in Python. Have you checked the official OpenAI library for C#? Did you encounter a problem?

@PanagiotisKanavos I have used the openAI library in the code for generating responses one at a time and It is working fine. What I am not able to get is I want to generate the responses all together and in a single file which can be done through Batch API

Using which library? What did you try? If you used the official library, did you create a BatchClient?

@PanagiotisKanavos I have edited and replaced the code with what I have done till now
